# Want to change values in a column to 0

Tags: python, for-loop, rename

In my dataframe, I have a series called 'Proposed Price' where it has prices and occasionally a string labeled "Price Removed". I am trying to change the Price Removed to 0.

I am not sure how to approach this. I tried a for loop and a renaming code. Both didn't give me errors but didn't actually change the Price Removed to 0's.

Can someone help me out?

my for loop was

```
 for x in analysis['Proposed Price']:
   if x == 'Price Removed':
     x == 0
  else:
     analysis['Proposed Price'] = analysis['Proposed Price'].str.replace("$", "").str.replace(",","")
```

Another code was :

```
analysis['Proposed Price'] = analysis['Proposed Price'].rename({'Price Removed' : 0})
```

How can I successfully change the stings to 0's so I can finally get a column of all floats?

Comment: You should provide example input. I guess when you use term dataframe it means you are using Pandas but structure of `analysis` is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

analysis['Proposed Price']= analysis['Proposed Price'].replace(to_replace= 'Price Removed' , value= 0, inplace=False)

This code works!